# Single static page with a navigation page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to create a Simple Xamarins forms App with a main page (static) containing a header, a footer. Inside that static page i would like a content area where i can use the navigation [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toINw.png)

I tried to use master details and navigation but that templates are too complex for my need. I was thinking about Navigation page in a page content but it's not working..
Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a `ContentView` and just use it on every page!? In my understanding, this would be better than a static approach which would lead to memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Based off the design provided, I would recommend a Master-Detail layout. As you have previously stated, the default navigation may not be what you want. If you are looking to simply replace the main page content without any type of page stack, you could replace any `Navigation.Push...()` uses with `MasterPage.Detail = ...`

Another method would be to use ContentView as previously stated. This would look something like

```
<!-- Master Page-->
<ContentPage> 
    <!-- Page Container -->
    <StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Header -->
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <ContentView x:Name="MainContent"/>

        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Footer -->  
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and you would be able to change pages from the code behind like 
`MainContent.Content = new MyContentView();`

Comment: Thanks for your answers !
In my main page there is a news list view, and i use the navigation page with the select item event to see more details about the news. Is there a way to use navigation page Inside a content view ? With that way i can keep my main page who has containing my header, footer etc...
I checked the master details, but i dont need the menu..

Comment: @Diecydius I don't think you can use navigation page Inside a content view.

Comment: Arf.. Ok thank u for your answer.. So I gonna check another way to do Something different, maybe with control template